# Cap element size to grid area when using align-item: start

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid with a scrollable element placed in one of the grid's areas.

[image: Scrollable item in grid]

What'd I'd like is for the item to shrink if the content is too small to fit the area. I did this by setting `align-self` to `start`.

[image: align-self is start]

This works great, until the content grows. The element resizes past the end of the grid area it's assigned to.

[image: overflowing element]

How can I use align-start but still cap the height to the height of the grid area? I would have expected this to be the default behavior.

One solution is to have the element stretch but then have a child element inside it that contains the actual content. The parent would have overflow: auto and the child would simply grow until it's too large for the container. Unfortunately, this kills the box-shadow.

[image: no box shadow]

I could put the box-shadow on the outer element in this case, but then it'll be too large when the content is small.

[image: shadow too large]

Any ideas what I can do here? I considered using some Javascript shinnanigans but I'm not even sure how I'd grab the height of the grid area from JS.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1kLenm5a/2/

Comment: max-height:100% ?

Comment: I swear I tried that half a dozen times and it didn't work but apparently it just fixed it in the fiddle. Let me try in my real environment to make sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: lol okay that works. Thanks. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `max-height: 100%` works. I could have sworn I tried that but I was messing with so many other settings at the same time I must have missed it.

Thanks.